# Set marker color in plotly scatter plot based on data.frame column

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `data.frame` that I'm trying to plot using `plotly`. I want to do a `line` plot with two variables and set the marker color based on a third variable. Below example shows what this looks like using `mtcars` as a sample dataset.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
plot_ly(as.data.table(mtcars)[order(wt)]) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, color = ~vs, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')
```

The output looks like: 
[image]

In my actual dataset, as in `mtcars`, the variable can take discrete values (0 or 1). By default `plotly` treats it as a continuous variable with a colorbar in the legend. I would like to show only two colors corresponding to the two values the variable can assume and not show any color bar.

I've tried setting the variable as a factor but that returns two line plots, which is not what I want:

```
plot_ly(as.data.table(mtcars)[order(wt)]) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, color = ~as.factor(vs), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')
```

[image]

I've also tried to set the marker color alone based on the third variable:

```
plot_ly(as.data.table(mtcars)[order(wt)]) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, color = ~as.factor(vs), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')
```

This works but I'm not able to specify the colors for the two `levels`. I've tried using `marker = list(colors = c('green', 'red', ...)` without any success.

[image]

To summarize, I want to display a single line plot (uniform color) for two variables with markers set to two discrete colors (no colorbar) that I specify based on the value of a third variable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to set the color of each marker manually as follows, you can specify the colors based on the value of the third variable `vs` in the `recode()` function below.

```
data <- data.frame(mtcars,stringsAsFactors = F)
data <- data %>% 
  arrange(wt) %>% 
  mutate(vs = as.character(vs),
         color = recode(vs,`1` = "red",
                        `0` = "blue"))

plot_ly(data) %>% 
       add_trace(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
                 marker = list(color = ~color))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before but I want some approach 'by reference' (if that makes sense) because I may have other variables with more `levels` in the future that I want to plot